# Error in php-fpm.log (another instance already listening) - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

Today, I started getting a 502 Bad Gateway error in a Laravel app I am working on. After hours of research and combing through my codebase I see that php-fpm is not working correctly with Laravel Valet.

The 502 Bad Gateway error happens on registration in the Laravel app.

In the php-fpm.log I see the following message:

```
[09-Jul-2019 16:38:42] ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /Users/daniel/.config/valet/valet.sock
[09-Jul-2019 16:38:42] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

I have tried uninstalling php, nginx, and valet numerous times. Tried different versions of php from 5.6 to 7.3. Restarted my macbook multiple times. Cleared the cache in my browser. Tried a different browser. Nothing seems to be fixing it.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user "daniel" staff;
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    ssi on;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/x-component;

    include "/Users/daniel/.config/valet/Nginx/*";
    include servers/*;
    include valet/valet.conf;
}
```

Anyone have any other suggestions for fixing this? My last resort is doing a complete rebuild of my macbook, but I would rather not if I can help it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to restart your php-fpm service?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Yes, I have done that also.

Comment: Update your post with nginx parameters pls

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco not sure what you mean by parameters. Sorry.

Comment: the nginx config file for your website

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I added the contents of the nginx.conf file. I hope that is what you were referring to.

Comment: You posted a main config file, it should be another one located in sites-enabled folder

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I don't have a sites-enabled or sites-available folder.

Comment: This config does not belong to your site, and it does not have any parameters to config what php*-fpm to use. Here is the example how config for laravel supposed to look like: https://gist.github.com/zechtz/6cec31ef3771674ef34e9d9138760097

Comment: post your server config files in conf.d,sites-enabled folder